# Why firebase is giving key name but returning value=null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a small application in which I am getting the location(lat, long)from the firebase database and showing that location on the map.But firebase returning the null values.

here is database structure

[image]

Here is my code

```
 lat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Its me").child("latitude").child("location");
 lon =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Its me").child("longitude").child("location");

    lat.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            latitude = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    lon.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            longitude = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
    latitude.replaceAll(",",".");
    longitude.replaceAll(",",".");
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    double lat= Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    double lon= Double.parseDouble(longitude);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

}
```

Dont know what is missing.Please help:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see what is happening is by simplifying your code and placing a few log statements:

```
lat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Its me").child("latitude").child("location");
System.out.println("Before attaching listener");
lat.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("In onDataChange");
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
}
System.out.println("After attaching listener");
```

The code will print:

> Before attaching listener
>
> After attaching listener
>
> In onDataChange

This is probably not the order that you expected, but it is working as expected. Since it may take some time before the data is loaded, Firebase let's your code continue so that the user doesn't get an "Application Not Responding" dialog. Then once the value is loaded, Firebase invokes your `onDataChange` method.

The solution is to move all code that requires the data into the `onDataChange()` or at least to invoke all code that requires the data from `onDataChange()`. In your case that is slightly more complicated because you use two listeners. Given your data structure, I recommend using a single listener to keep things simple:

```
ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Its me")
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        longitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude/location").getValue(String.class);
        latitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude/location").getValue(String.class);
        latitude.replaceAll(",",".");
        longitude.replaceAll(",",".");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```